# Find closest elements from arrays which follow a trend

Tags: algorithm

I have three integer arrays A,B,C.

I want to find the closest a,b,c such that

a < b < c where a belongs to A, b belongs to B and c belongs to C.

When I say closest I  mean (b-a) + (c-b) = (c-a) is minimum.

Framed this question myself. I can only think of brute force which will be O(N^3)

Comment: homework ? Anyway , please post what you've done to find the solution and where you failed..

Comment: I am too old to get homeworks :P . Framed this question myself. I can only think of brute force which will be O(N^3)

Comment: This may not help (yet) but notice that (b-a)+(c-b)=c-a... so it is probably simpler to just minimize c-a (same thing).

Comment: Yea, I made that observation forgot to mention it.

Comment: @TravisJ not at all. Your suggestion greatly reduces the complexity of the problem

Comment: In general, if you found a question on another site, it's likely to have been asked here before. Dupehammer incoming.

Comment: David .. didn't get you. Where is this question asked before? :P .. You have given link to this question only

Comment: @David you missed the a<b<c  part.

Comment: Trivial difference. Not voting to reopen.

Comment: This is trivial? Really ..lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TravisJ mentions the value you are optimizing is `(b-a) + (c-b) = c - a` Thus you only need to minimize the difference between two elements - one from the first set and one from the third. One possible approach I can think of is - sort the elements in `C` and then iterate over all elements in `A`. For each `a` from `A` you can do a binary search in the sorted `C` to find the element `c` closest to the given `a`. Optimize over all value `c-a` obtained in this manner. This solution will have complexity `O(n * log(n))`.

EDIT: (again as suggested by TravisJ): you will need to make sure there is a `b` from `B` such that `a < b < c`. To do that you will need to also sort `B`. Now for each `a` you perform a binary search in `B` to find the smallest `b` larger than `a` and then another binary in `c` to find the smallest `c` larger than `b`.

Comment: You just have to make sure there is an element of B in between the a and c...

Comment: you missed the "b" .. :)

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal not really bu TravisJ makes a good comment. You will need to make sure there is a `b` between the chosen pair `a` and `c`. You can do that by sorting `B` too and performing another binary in it

Comment: Then it does not stay nlogn anymore ..

Comment: I am new here. Not able to understand why this question is marked duplicate.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal it does.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal take a look at the linked question and its answers. Whoever marked your question as duplicate thought that these answers answer your question too.

Comment: How ? We will have to check for all the closest pair of c,a if b exists or not such that a<b<c  in worst case there can be as many closest a,c pairs as n

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each element c of C. Use a binary search on B to find the largest element b such that b < c. Use a binary search on A to find the largest element a such that a < b. (If either a or b does not exist, go on to the next c.) Compute c-a; if it is less than any c-a seen previously, set this as the best seen so far. At the end return the best seen so far, or "impossible" if you never find a suitable triple. This takes O(n log n).